# App automatically closes after opening

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, wallpaper

I am posting xml codes, it is not running on AVD and device:
I haven't coded any logic for Java it is simply a blank file, and it is as below:

Problem i am facing is i am not able to run this app, it automatically closes after opening and i don't know why, i am unable to figure any mistake since 6 hours, please help if any bug is there, or if any other information is required

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SetWall extends Activity {

    ImageView IVdisplay, IVimage1,IVimage2, IVimage3, IVimage4, IVimage5, IVimage6 ;
    Button bsetwall;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.set_wall, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/xda"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"
        android:id="@+id/IVdisplay"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView

        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/xda1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"

        android:id="@+id/IVimage1"/>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/xda2"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"

        android:id="@+id/IVimage2"/>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/xda3"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"
        android:id="@+id/IVimage3"/>

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/xda4"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"
        android:id="@+id/IVimage4"/>

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/xda5"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"
        android:id="@+id/IVimage5"/>

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/xda6"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name_inside"
        android:id="@+id/IVimage6"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsetwall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/setwallbutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall"
            android:label="@string/app_name_inside" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LOGCAT FILE:

```
> 10-23 08:44:14.962: D/dalvikvm(1338): Not late-enabling CheckJNI
> (already on) 10-23 08:44:20.432: D/dalvikvm(1338): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed
> 55K, 4% free 3091K/3216K, paused 58ms, total 61ms 10-23 08:44:20.442:
> I/dalvikvm-heap(1338): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.752MB for
> 702736-byte allocation 10-23 08:44:20.512: D/dalvikvm(1338):
> GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3775K/3904K, paused 67ms, total 67ms
> 10-23 08:44:23.452: D/dalvikvm(1338): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free
> 3799K/3904K, paused 40ms, total 41ms 10-23 08:44:23.452:
> I/dalvikvm-heap(1338): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for
> 14004244-byte allocation 10-23 08:44:23.522: D/dalvikvm(1338):
> GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 3% free 3789K/3904K, paused 63ms, total 64ms
> 10-23 08:44:23.522: E/dalvikvm-heap(1338): Out of memory on a
> 14004244-byte allocation. 10-23 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338): "main"
> prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE 10-23 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338):   |
> group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb4a34c90 self=0xb8440380 10-23
> 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338):   | sysTid=1338 nice=0 sched=0/0
> cgrp=apps handle=-1225678508 10-23 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338):   |
> state=R schedstat=( 3680000000 3540000000 354 ) utm=301 stm=67 core=0
> 10-23 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
> 10-23 08:44:23.532: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall.onCreate(SetWall.java:18)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-23 08:44:23.542:
> I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-23 08:44:23.542:
> I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
> 10-23 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 10-23
> 08:44:23.542: I/dalvikvm(1338):   at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-23 08:44:23.542:
> D/skia(1338): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap 10-23
> 08:44:23.612: D/AndroidRuntime(1338): Shutting down VM 10-23
> 08:44:23.612: W/dalvikvm(1338): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> uncaught exception (group=0xb4a33b90) 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338): Process: delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers,
> PID: 1338 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers/delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error
> inflating class <unknown> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
> Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown> 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall.onCreate(SetWall.java:18)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   ... 11 more 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     ... 26 more 10-23 08:44:23.702:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1338): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
> 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):   at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119) 10-23
> 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     ... 29 more 10-23 08:44:26.422:
> I/Process(1338): Sending signal. PID: 1338 SIG: 9 10-23 08:45:21.512:
> D/dalvikvm(1381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 4% free 3091K/3220K, paused
> 53ms, total 56ms 10-23 08:45:21.522: I/dalvikvm-heap(1381): Grow heap
> (frag case) to 3.752MB for 702736-byte allocation 10-23 08:45:21.662:
> D/dalvikvm(1381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3775K/3908K, paused
> 137ms, total 137ms 10-23 08:45:24.542: D/dalvikvm(1381): GC_FOR_ALLOC
> freed 2K, 3% free 3799K/3908K, paused 69ms, total 70ms 10-23
> 08:45:24.542: I/dalvikvm-heap(1381): Forcing collection of
> SoftReferences for 14004244-byte allocation 10-23 08:45:24.612:
> D/dalvikvm(1381): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 4% free 3789K/3908K, paused
> 68ms, total 69ms 10-23 08:45:24.612: E/dalvikvm-heap(1381): Out of
> memory on a 14004244-byte allocation. 10-23 08:45:24.612:
> I/dalvikvm(1381): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE 10-23 08:45:24.612:
> I/dalvikvm(1381):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb4a34c90
> self=0xb8440380 10-23 08:45:24.622: I/dalvikvm(1381):   | sysTid=1381
> nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1225678508 10-23 08:45:24.622:
> I/dalvikvm(1381):   | state=R schedstat=( 3540000000 950000000 230 )
> utm=279 stm=75 core=0 10-23 08:45:24.622: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:45:24.622: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
> 10-23 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
> 10-23 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
> 10-23 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110) 10-23
> 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 10-23
> 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129) 10-23
> 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119) 10-23
> 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 10-23
> 08:45:24.632: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall.onCreate(SetWall.java:18)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-23 08:45:24.642:
> I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-23 08:45:24.642:
> I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
> 10-23 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 10-23
> 08:45:24.642: I/dalvikvm(1381):   at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-23 08:45:24.642:
> D/skia(1381): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap 10-23
> 08:45:24.712: D/AndroidRuntime(1381): Shutting down VM 10-23
> 08:45:24.712: W/dalvikvm(1381): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> uncaught exception (group=0xb4a33b90) 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Process: delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers,
> PID: 1381 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers/delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error
> inflating class <unknown> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
> Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown> 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> delhi.digitek.androidlhdwallpapers.SetWall.onCreate(SetWall.java:18)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   ... 11 more 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 26 more 10-23 08:45:24.812:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
> 10-23 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):   at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at
> android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119) 10-23
> 08:45:24.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 29 more
```

Comment: wats the problem exactly? does the app crash? show blank screen? something else?

Comment: It just closes down after opening, no crash message, no blank screen, othing else. I open the app, it closes.

Comment: the stack trace clearly says what's wrong: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31`. check the area around the line #31 in your layout file

Comment: `Out of memory on a 14004244-byte allocation` may be your image is a little too big?

Comment: make sure all images name in lower case not underscore or any special character  , and not in big size

Answer (score 1):

did you register your activity on AndroidManifest.xml ??
add your SetWall Activity.
if it's not the case see your logcat carefully and it'll tell you what you missed

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 10-23 08:44:23.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575) 10-23 08:44:2

it says - caused by out of memory error. 
It means your image is too much big. test with small size images first.
If you want to show high quality images you should show them one by one. not at same time.
In your xml I see many pictures included.

in this case I recommend you to use programmatically

for outofmemory issue you should do sampling.

```
BitmapFactory.Options option = new Options();
option.inSampleSize = 2;
```

(1 means original, 2 means sampling your image half, 3 is not supported is equal as 2, 4..., 8...)

```
Bitmap samplingBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, option);
imageView.setImageBitmap(samplingBitmap);
```

I recommend you to use asset folder .
put your images in asset folder then your images path will be file:///android_asset/***.jpg

Comment: Yes friend i have that registered in manifest, the app is instantly forced to close after iitiated running.

Comment: if you can get log cat and show me, it will help me understand the situation. Your code seems fine.

Comment: Yes i have attacehd the log cat error, please check

Answer (score 1):

sorry i am posting this as an answer because i dont have the reputation to comment.
but since your exception is about inflating, bitmapfactory and outofmemoryexception i guess the problem is about your imageviews in your layouts having to big images to be loaded into the memory of your device you're running your code on. try removing the sources of your imageviews and running it without them.